# How to extract any given number from a dataframe and assign it a name

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I extract a number in any given location of a dataframe? Let's say I have a 4x4 matrix, how would I take the number value in (2,4) and assign that value a name?

Comment: A matrix and a data frame aren't the same. Maybe I'm missing something—it seems like you're just trying to get a value by index, such as `x <- dat[2,4]`?

Comment: Please give an example of input/expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the setNames function as so: `setNames(value, c(name1))`

This works for vectors and columns too- for instance: `setNames(df[c(col1, col2), c(name1, name2)];` and `setNames(c(val1, val2, val3), c(name1, name2, name3))`

Edit-

```
#dataframe with one row and two columns as such
df <- data.frame('a','b')

#You can access a value by:
val <- levels(droplevels(df[1,2]))  #Value at first row, second column

#To assign it a name, you can either use:
setNames(val, c(name))

#or

names(val) <- c(name)
```

Hope this helps!